# Service Intent not found Android plugin for Unity

Tags: java, c#, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm a bit new to developing for android, but I feel like I've scoured quite a few forums and tried everything I can find, to no avail.

At any rate, I'm trying to build an Android plugin for my Unity project, and essentially I'd like to start an Android service from Unity. It seems as though I have all my ducks in a row, but when it goes to start the service, I get the following error message on the Android Monitor LogCat:

```
 Unable to start service Intent{ cmd=com.activetime.androidplugin/.services.StepsService } U=0; not found
```

My suspicion is that the "/" between "androidplugin" and ".services" isn't suppose to be there, which is why it can't find the service, but I can't for the life of me figure out why it's there. I've seen other similar issues out there but none of the solutions seem to work; perhaps there's some issue with merging manifests?

In any case, here's the Java class from Android Studio:

```
private static DBReader instance;

     public DBReader(){
         this.instance = this;
     }

     public static DBReader instance(){
         if(instance == null){
             instance = new DBReader();
         }
         return instance;
     }

     public void startStepsService(Activity unityActivity){
         unityActivity.startService(new Intent(unityActivity, StepsService.class));
     }

}
```

And then the C# in Unity:

```
void Start(){
     #if UNITY_ANDROID

     using(AndroidJavaClass activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
         activityContext = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
     }

     using(AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.activetime.androidplugin.DBReader")) {
         if(pluginClass != null) {
             databaseplugin = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
             databaseplugin.Call("startStepsService", activityContext);
         }
     }

     #endif

 }
```

And finally my Android Studio XML manifest:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 package="com.activetime.androidplugin">

 <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:supportsRtl="true">

     <service
         android:name="com.activetime.androidplugin.services.StepsService">
     </service>

 </application>
```

Comment: have you tried making your instance public? 

public static DBReader instance;

Comment: Just tried making it public—same message.